# Normalize Special Letter Char from Various Foreigner Languages

Tags: javascript, normalize

Forgive my ignorance for not knowing the technical term for foreigner languages that use characters as

- **ø** i.e. Helsingør
- **Ł** i.e Łeczna
- **ı** i.e Altınordu
- **ł** i.e. Głogow

how could I normalize those with Javascript (**write a regex**), while also making case insentive?

```js
const strArr = ['Helsingør', 'Łeczna', 'Altınordu', 'Głogow', Népoão's]
```

With the code below, I was able to replace latin based characters (é, ñ, ô, etc) but not the above ones.

```js
strArr.map(string => string.normalize('NFD')
    .replaceAll(/[\u0300-\u036f,"\'"]/g, ''))
```

Mi final output should read as `['Helsingor', 'Leczna', 'Altinordu', 'Glogow', Nepoaos]`

Comment: Check my answer for removing special characters of foreign signs.

Comment: Now you can check updated code

Answer (score 0):

For replace non-ASCII characters with closet ASCII Character you need to use lodash library:

So your final code for replace special characters will be:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const strArr = ['Helsingør', 'Łeczna', 'Altınordu', 'Głogow'];
const normalized = strArr.map(string => _.deburr(string));

console.log(normalized);
```

**Output Result :**

```
[ 'Helsingor', 'Leczna', 'Altinordu', 'Glogow' ]
```

Comment: the regex shouldn't remove but rather replace with normalized characters i.e. `['Helsingor', 'Leczna', 'Altinordu', 'Glogow', Nepoaos]`

Comment: Code updated for your required output result

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered the `.normalize('NFD')` only decomposes Latin characters. You'd need to use library that normalizes other languages, possibly https://github.com/walling/unorm.

You can also roll your own. Here is a solution that uses the `.normalize('NFD')` in conjunction with a `iMap` object that maps from international to English characters. This `iMap` is short, you can expand as needed, such as taking the mapping from https://github.com/cvan/lunr-unicode-normalizer/blob/master/lunr.unicodeNormalizer.js. You can also override the mapping of `.normalize('NFD')`, for example, umlaut `ü` is better mapped to `ue` instead of `u`.

```js
function normalizeString(str) {
  const iMap = {
    'ð': 'd',
    'ı': 'i',
    'Ł': 'L',
    'ł': 'l',
    'ø': 'o',
    'ß': 'ss',
    'ü': 'ue'
  };
  const iRegex = new RegExp(Object.keys(iMap).join('|'), 'g')
  return str
    .replace(iRegex, (m) => iMap[m])
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
}

[
  'Helsingør', 'Łeczna', 'Altınordu', 'Głogow',
  'Áfram með smjörið', 'Crème Brulée', 'Bär Müller Straße'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = normalizeString(str);
  console.log(str, '=>', result);
});
```

Output:

```
Helsingør => Helsingor
Łeczna => Leczna
Altınordu => Altinordu
Głogow => Glogow
Áfram með smjörið => Afram med smjorid
Crème Brulée => Creme Brulee
Bär Müller Straße => Bar Mueller Strasse
```

Comment: thanks alot. just curious how would I make that implementation case insensitive?

Comment: You can't, but then it's easy to add `'Æ': 'AE', 'æ': 'ae'`